# I want to use the .py file in Django but faced some issues I'm totally new and need some solution

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have made a python script to find the subnet mask for the given number of host. But I want it to take HTML input on button click and pass it as user input in python script and give the output on same HTML page.
I have tried to give you guys max details of this program
I'm not able to understand the problem. it shows taking input in url like here the terminal output is for input 500

**urls.py**

```
path('findSM_H', views.findSM_H, name='findSM_H'),
   path('findSM_Houtput', views.findSM_Hexecution, name='findSM_Houtput')
```

**findSM_H.html**

```
<form method="GET" action="/findSM_H">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="450">
                    <table width="450">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                \\TAKING INPUT FROM THE USER
                                <td width="250" height="50">
                                    <label for="noofhostinput"> Number of host </label>
                                </td>
                                <td width="250" height="50">
                                    //ON CLICKING THE BUTTON IT TAKES TO 'findSM_Houtput' FUNCTION
                                    <input id="noofhostinput" type="text" name="noofhostinput" />
                                        <input type="submit" onclick="location.href ='{%url 'findSM_Houtput'%}'" >
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="30"></td>
                <td width="450">
                    <table width="450">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="250" height="50">
                                    //OUTPUT OF THE USER INPUT
                                    <label for="subnetmask"> Subnet mask </label>
                                </td>
                                <td width="200" height="50">
                                    <div  id="subnetmask" style="background-color: ddb(39, 6, 39)" type="text">
                                       00{{noofhost_op}}
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>0.{{noofhost_op}}</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def findSM_H(request):
    return render(request, 'findSM_H.html')

def findSM_Hexecution(request):
    noofhost_input = request.GET.get("noofhostinput")
    noofhost_output = run([sys.executable, 'D:\\Network_Project\\NetworkTools\\use_host_to_find_subnet_Mask_with_value.py',
                          noofhost_input], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    print(noofhost_output)

    return render(request, 'findSM_H.html', {'noofhost_op': noofhost_output})
```

**use_host_to_find_subnet_Mask_with_value.py**

```
import sys


noofhostinput="%s" % (sys.argv[1])
usr = int(noofhostinput)

table = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,
32768,65536,131072,262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,8388608,16777216]

for i in table:
    if usr < i:
        n = table.index(i)
        break       
csm = 32- n
if csm >=8 or csm<33:
    sm={'8':'255.0.0.0',
        '9':'255.128.0.0',
        '10':'255.192.0.0',
        '11':'255.224.0.0',
        '12':'255.240.0.0',
        '13':'255.248.0.0',
        '14':'255.252.0.0',
        '15':'255.254.0.0',
        '16':'255.255.0.0',
        '17':'255.255.128.0',
        '18':'255.255.192.0',
        '19':'255.255.224.0',
        '20':'255.255.240.0',
        '21':'255.255.248.0',
        '22':'255.255.252.0',
        '23':'255.255.254.0',
        '24':'255.255.255.0',
        '25':'255.255.255.128',
        '26':'255.255.255.192',
        '27':'255.255.255.224',
        '28':'255.255.255.240',
        '29':'255.255.255.248',
        '30':'255.255.255.252',
        '31':'255.255.255.254',
        '32':'255.255.255.255'}
    for i in range(8,33):
        if i == csm:
            j= str(i)
            output = f'your subnet mask for {usr} Host is {sm[j]}/{csm}'
            print(output)
else:

    output="your value is out of range of valid subnet mask."
    print(output)
```

**terminal log**

```
[14/Feb/2022 05:45:30] "GET /findSM_H?csrfmiddlewaretoken=4SK8zRYZkwzVYb8RP80A8Wu3tILyhJGejbsAfKTHUAh9VgjGMfDdFjtSVFLexTlD&noofhostinput=500 HTTP/1.1" 200 4868Internal Server Error: /findSM_Houtput
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NIRMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\NIRMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Network_Project\NetworkTools\NetworkApps\views.py", line 24, in findSM_Hexecution
    noofhost_output = run([sys.executable, 'D:\\Network_Project\\NetworkTools\\use_host_to_find_subnet_Mask_with_value.py',
  File "C:\Users\NIRMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\NIRMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\NIRMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1360, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\NIRMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 565, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
  File "C:\Users\NIRMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 822, in fsdecode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
[14/Feb/2022 05:45:30,806] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 49451)
```

Guys what is wrong here, what is django trying to say?
any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if noofhost_input is empty upon submission from browser because I think your form input submission action is overwritten (see below):

```
def findSM_Hexecution(request):
    noofhost_input = request.GET.get("noofhostinput")
    print("******",noffhost_input,"*****")
    noofhost_output = run([sys.executable, 'D:\\Network_Project\\NetworkTools\\use_host_to_find_subnet_Mask_with_value.py',
                          noofhost_input], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    print(noofhost_output)
```

I suppose noffhost_input is empty because the onclick definition is overwriting the form action but does not submit the input fields values of the form.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href ='{%url 'findSM_Houtput'%}'"
```

by the way: the form action points to another adress.
Solution is to remove the onclick...  and point the form action to findSM_Houtput.

Comment: Thanks buddy changing the name in action from action="/findSM_H" to  action="/findSM_Houtput" solved this one but now I'm getting an output in bytes `CompletedProcess(args=['C:\\Users\\NIRMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe', 'D:\\Network_Project\\NetworkTools\\use_host_to_find_subnet_Mask_with_value.py', '123'], returncode=0, **stdout=b'your subnet mask for 123 Host is 255.255.255.128/25\r\n'**)` How can I get rid of b'\r\n'

Comment: add "text=True" to the run(...) command

Comment: Now one more question. Lets say I'm making a program with 2 variables. For example, first it asks for IP address  then lets say it asks for 2nd variable. So how can I pass two variables? What changes should I have to make in my program to do that?

Comment: You mean add an Input besides '<input id="noofhostinput" ....' ?    just add an <input ..> with a different id inside the form in html and get it in the view with  'sec_input = request.GET.get("another_id")'